# Input validation not detecting empty value

Tags: javascript

So I have an issue where I need to make my code when the mouse leaves an input field and the input field is either  empty or has less than 5 characters it outputs something

I have tried putting .value after the getelementbyid. Please know that I can't use a button to submit the form.

```
var username = document.getElementById('username');
var user_length = username.length;

username.onmouseout = function(){
    if(username == ""){
        alert('hi');
        // var username_value = 
        //document.getElementById("username_output");
        // username_value.innerHTML ="Please fill in your username!";
        // username_value.style.color = 'red';
    }

    else if(user_length < 5){
        alert('smaller than 5');
    }
    else{
        alert('else');
    }
};
```

Whenever the mouse leaves it should output something. For some reason it's only going in the else statement not the other statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing the `input` itself (the DOM element, the result of `document.getElementById('username')`) with a string, not the input's *value*.

You want its `value` property:

```
if (username.value == "") {
```

But note that the user might type in a space, in which case the above would be false because `" "` is not equal to `""`. You can use `trim` to fix that:

```
if (username.value.trim() == "") {
```

Since empty strings are *falsy*¹, you can also save some typing:

```
if (!username.value.trim()) {
```

---

¹ "falsy" - Any JavaScript value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean is called a *falsy* value. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; all other values are *truthy*.